# C++11: Do move semantics get involved for pass by value?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I've got an API that looks like this:

```
void WriteDefaultFileOutput(std::wostream &str, std::wstring target)
{
    //Some code that modifies target before printing it and such...
}
```

I'm wondering if it'd be sensible to enable move semantics by doing this:

```
void WriteDefaultFileOutput(std::wostream &str, std::wstring&& target)
{
    //As above
}
void WriteDefaultFileOutput(std::wostream &str, std::wstring const& target)
{
    std::wstring tmp(target);
    WriteDefaultFileOutput(str, std::move(tmp));
}
```

or is this just boilerplate that the compiler should be able to figure out anyway?

Comment: The wstring has a move constructor, so isn't this what is happening already?

Comment: Can't you avoid the tmp and the std::move and pass wstring(target) in the function call directly?

Comment: This is maybe a stupid question, but why is passing a plain normal const reference not an option? Writing something (here: a string) to a stream should not modify it, nor require an extra, private copy. So, I really don't see the reasoning behind first making a (possibly deep) temporal copy and then using (destructive) move semantics on the temporary. Except for the sake of using move semantics, of course.

Comment: @Damon : A comment in the code shown explicitly says `//Some code that modifies target before printing it and such...`.

Comment: Ah, silly me... missed that comment, thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Pass by value" can mean either copy or move; if the argument is an lvalue, the copy constructor is invoked. If the argument is an rvalue, the move constructor is invoked. You don't have to do anything special involving rvalue references to get move semantics with pass by value.

I dig deeper into this topic in [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/)

Comment: In the case of pass by value, and an rvalue argument, I'd expect the temporary to be constructed exactly where it was needed, so that there wouldn't be anything to move.  Or to copy, in older compilers.

Comment: Maybe; compiler optimization land is not my territory.

Comment: It's hardly what I would call optimization (although officially it is).  Eliding of a copy constructor can result in a change in program semantics, is only legal because the standard gives the compiler explicit authorization to do it, and because it may change the semantics, must be taken into account when evaluating program correctness.

Comment: Anyway, the optimization you mention is only possible with prvalues, not xvalues.

Answer (score 3):

You should prefer pass-by-value if you're going to make a copy with non-movable values. For example, your `const&` version of `WriteDefaultFileOutput` explicitly copies the parameter, then moves the copy with the move version. Which means if `WriteDefaultFileOutput` is called with a movable value (xvalue or prvalue), then it will be moved, and if it's called with an lvalue, it will be copied.

This means that there is *no* difference between the two forms of this function. Consider this:

```
WriteDefaultFileOutput(L"SomeString");
```

In your first case, it will create a temporary `wstring`. Temporaries are prvalues, so it will be "moved" into the parameter (since `wstring` has a move constructor). Of course, any compiler worth its salt will elide the move and simply construct the temporary directly into the parameter.

In your second case, more or less the same thing happens. A temporary `wstring` is created. Temporaries are prvalues, so they can bind to `&&` parameter types. Therefore, it will call the first version of your function with an r-value reference to the temporary. The only possible difference would be from a compiler that won't elide the move. And even then, a move isn't that expensive (depending on your `basic_string` implementation).

Now consider this:

```
std::wstring myStr{L"SomeString"};
WriteDefaultFileOutput(myStr);
```

In the first case, the call to `WriteDefaultFileOutput` will cause a copy of the `myStr` value into the function parameter.

In the second case, `myStr` is an lvalue. It *cannot* bind to a `&&` parameter. Therefore, the only version it can call is the `const&` version. That function will manually construct a copy, and then move the copy with the other one.

An identical effect. Your first version has less code, so go with that for obvious reasons.

In general, I would say that there are only two reasons to take a parameter as a `&&`:

1. You are writing a move constructor.
2. You are writing a forwarding function and need to use perfect forwarding.

In all other cases where you want movement to be possible, just take a value. If the user wants to copy, let them copy. I suppose if you want to explicitly forbid copying of the parameter, you could take a `&&`. But the main issue is one of clarity.

If you take a value parameter, and the user provides a moveable value, then the user-provided value will *always* be moved. For example, your `&&` version of `WriteDefaultFileOutput` does not *have* to actually move the data from its parameter. It certainly can. But it doesn't have to. If it took a value, then it would already have claimed the data.

Therefore, if a function takes a value parameter, and you see a `std::move` into that value, then you *know* that the object which was moved is now empty. It is *guaranteed* to have been moved from.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly correct @fredoverflow answer

Pass by value can mean either copy or move from argument into parameter

- If the argument is lvalue, the copy constructor is invoked.
- If the argument is rvalue reference, the move constructor is invoked.
- If the argument is rvalue, no copy or move is invoked. (Copy elision kicks in)

See https://godbolt.org/z/Mn56cb949

```cpp
int f(A a) {
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    return a.x + a.y;
}

A a{1, 2};
// move construct A
f(std::move(a));

// no copy or move
f(A{1, 2});
```