# C++ Pass by value with perfect rvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

This might just be a "vocabulary issue", but there is something I don't get with rvalue references and pass by value.

If I have a code like this ([ideone it](https://ideone.com/uz4Smw))

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo()                 { printf("Ctor\n"); }
    Foo(const Foo& other) { printf("Copy\n"); }
    Foo(Foo&& other)      { printf("Move\n"); }
    ~Foo()                { printf("Dtor\n"); }
};

void DoFoo(Foo foo) { printf("Foo\n"); }

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    DoFoo(foo);
    DoFoo(Foo{});
    return 0;
}
```

it will give me this output ([ideone result](https://ideone.com/uz4Smw) copy pasted)

```
Ctor 0x96eaa10 0
Copy 0x96eaa20 0
Foo  0x96eaa20 0
Dtor 0x96eaa20
Ctor 0x96eaa20 1
Foo  0x96eaa20 1
Dtor 0x96eaa20
Dtor 0x96eaa10
```

What I don't understand is, according to many stackoverflow answers, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592741/4717805) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9724935/4717805), the *move constructor* should be called for the `DoFoo(Foo{})`, but it's clearly not, and the behaviour is the same with or without a `Foo` *move constructor*.

Even replacing `DoFoo(Foo foo)` by `DoFoo(Foo&& foo)` does not force the call to the *move constructor*.

So, is it just a vocabulary issue when using *moved* in these particular case ? Is it a GCC particular behaviour? or anything else ?

Comment: Yes sure, I feel rather stupid not having thought about it actually... Was totally focusing on the `move constructed` fact and forgot about copy elision. You can make an answer (with a bit more explanations about copy elision) I'll accept it.

Comment: `DoFoo(Foo&&)` would certainly **not** call any move constructor, since it accepts a reference.  (Since C++17, neither does `DoFoo(Foo)` with a prvalue argument.)